# Parsing HTTP request and response from a text file in java

Tags: java, regex

We have a request/response of the following form in a text file-

> POST /bWAPP/xss_post.php HTTP/1.1 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>   6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0 Referer: http://9.123.241.46/bWAPP/xss_post.php Cookie:
>
> firstname=%3E%22%27%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%28192%29%3C%2Fscript%3E&lastname=%3E%22%27%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%28192%29%3C%2Fscript%3E&form=%3E%22%27%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%28192%29%3C%2Fscript%3E
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: Keep-Alive
>   Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.13 Pragma:

The string contains both request and response. I want to parse the request and  response from it. HTTP/1.1 comes two times: once in request and once in response. The response starts from the place where HTTP/1.1 comes second time. Please help me to write an appropriate regex pattern so as to extract the request and response separately from the given string.

Comment: I was able to parse the headers by using regex and hardcoding all the possible headers and getting the content between any header name and new line. For example,Accept:(.*?)\n.It returned me the Accept Header value for all requests.

Comment: If you enable multiline mode with `(?m)`, it should only require a simple pattern, such as `(?m)^HTTP/1\.1.+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an exercise, I used a variable-width negative look-ahead:

`(?<request>.*)(?<response>HTTP\/1\.1(?!.*HTTP\/1\.1).*)`

The idea is that at located from the end of the first HTTP-statement, it looks forwards and asserts another cannot be found.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VArr3r/1)